# Can we have different routeIDs for a specific route for multiple choices?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, activemq-classic, integration

I have one route in Camel class.I require different `routeIDs` for different choices. I.e. when `transtype=CXML` gets called, the `routeId` should be shown as `CXML` & when `transtype=OCI` gets called,the `routeId` should be shown as `OCI`.

There I am using different choices.

eg.

```
from(IntegrationConstants.JMSQUEUE)
    .process(routeHeaderProcessor)  
    .choice()
    .when(transtype=CXML) 
    .then(...........)
    .routeId(CXML)
    .when()
    .when(transtype=OCI) 
    .then(...........)
    .routeId(OCI)
```

However,when I run this program with `transType=CXML` or `OCI`, I get `routeId` as `OCI` only in the output.

Can you suggest how can I have different routeIDs for different choice of transType within the same route?

I am stuck on this for a while now. If not the `routeID`, can we assign some unique id to the different choice? So that we can make things more specific?

Comment: Please read [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to format your post.

Comment: You cannot change route id after the route has been started. As Petter says you can use other routes as sub-routes and link them using the direct endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Use "sub routes" using the direct transport for the various things done in each choice. Then you can set unique routeIds on each "sub route".

A direct invokation is as cheap as it gets.

Example from the web site:

```
 from("direct:a")
            .choice()
                .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar"))
                    .to("direct:b")
                .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("cheese"))
                    .to("direct:c")
                .otherwise()
                    .to("direct:d");
    }


  from("direct:b")
    .routeId("b")
    .doWhateverHere();

  from("direct:c")
    .routeId("c")
    .doWhateverHere();

  from("direct:d")
    .routeId("d")
    .doWhateverHere();
```

Comment: Can you please explain? I did understand. How can we create sub routes ?

Comment: Can you please explain little more ? I did not understand. How can we create sub routes ?  Sorry I am new to Camel,can you elaborate further?

Comment: added example in the question